# Car rattles when someone seats or go out of the car

Tags: suspension, shock-absorber, rattle, underbody

My car rattles when someone seats in the back passenger or when I push down the car trunk. The sound is coming from the back portion of the car.

Any idea what would be the problem?

**Car: Honda City 2003 A/T**

TIA?

Comment: This noise could be from any part of the car on some type of mounting : suspension parts or even the exhaust. Another possibility is that there is a loose bolt or screw in a cavity under the seat for example (had that and a so & so to find...).

Answer (score 1):

This noise could be from any part of the car on some type of flexible mounting : suspension parts or even the exhaust. Another possibility is that there is a loose bolt or screw in a cavity under the seat for example (had that and a so & so to find...). updated after your edit.